# javascript chrome localStorage async using promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, promise

Hello I'm making a chrome extension that will communicate with a webserver to log a user in, so I'm going to need to store the auth token locally in the chrome app, so you can stay logged in even if you close the extension.

I'm trying to do this with chrome's localstorage get/set methods. Initially I was running into some timing issues where getting a value after I set it wouldn't be correct.

So I'm trying to write my get / set methods in promise functions to ensure that they are only returned once the action has been successfully completed, but I'm still getting some issues. Right now for testing purposes my main code runs at the start of the extension:

```
//once popup window is fully loaded
window.onload = async function(){

    //set test var in localstorage to 3
    let result = await setVarInLocalStorage("test", 3)
    console.log("result resolve = " + result)

    //get test variable from localstorage (should be 3)
    let result1 = await getVarFromLocalStorage("test")
    console.log("result1 resolve = " + result1)

    //set test var in localstorage to 77
    let result2 = await setVarInLocalStorage("test", 77)
    console.log("result2 resolve = " + result2)

    //get test variable from localstorage (should be 77)
    let result3 = await getVarFromLocalStorage("test")
    console.log("result3 resolve = " + result3)
 }
```

My function to set variables in localstorage:

```
function setVarInLocalStorage(name, value){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("set: setting "+ name +" in localstorage to " + value)
        chrome.storage.sync.set({ name: value }, function(){
            resolve("var set successfully")
        });

    })
}
```

my function to get variables from localstorage:

```
function getVarFromLocalStorage(name){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("get: getting "+ name +" from localstorage")
        chrome.storage.sync.get([name], function(items){
            var target = items[name];
            console.log("   items[name] = " + target)
            resolve(target)
        });
    })
}
```

But when I run my extension I get some unexpected behavior:
[image]

is this a problem with how I set up my promise functions?

Comment: Move `resolve("var set successfully")` inside the callback of sync.set() call!

Comment: i edited my post to include this fix, but the result is still the same as my image

Comment: i think the problem is that Im trying to use a varaible with .set({ name:value }) , if i replace name with "test" it works fine. Im going to look into how to use a var in the set method

Comment: Oh indeed it should be `{[name]: value}`, see [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2274242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was a problem with my set function, fixed wih this:

```html
function setVarInLocalStorage(name, value){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //console.log("set: setting "+ name +" in localstorage to " + value)

        var name = 'k1';
        var obj= {};
        obj[name] = value;

       chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, function(){ 
            //console.log("set: localStorage[name] = " + localStorage[name])
            resolve("var set successfully")
        });
        
    })
}
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer. That way it wont pop up in the unanswered section!

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze i would but it says i have to wait untill tommorrow to accept it

Comment: @Martin it's tomorrow :D 

Also, what is `chrome.storage`